# Moving second row after fourth using awk

Tags: awk

I have a task to get the output of:

```
ps auxfwww | sort -k2n | head -n4
```

Then I have to rearrange it, using awk, so that I get as a result 1st,3rd,11th column of rows 2,3,4. But the rows must be in order 3,4,2. The closest I get is this:

```
ps auxfwww | sort -k2n | head -n4 | awk 'NR>=3' | awk '{print $1, $3, $11}'
```

But I have no idea how to get row 2 to get after rows 3 and 4.

It also has to be done with a single line command.

Please shed some light :)

Comment: Did you mean "in order 3,4,2" instead of "3,4,1" as written?  P.S. it is hilarious how you say it "has to be done with a single command" but your work so far uses five commands, including two `awk`s when one would do, and an unnecessary `head`.

Comment: It is indeed 3,4,2 I'll edit that. I mean a single line command, sorry about the misunderstanding, English is not my native language.

Answer (score 2):

```
ps auxfwww | sort -k2n | head -n4 | awk '{ a[i++] = $1" "$3" "$11 } END { print a[2]; print a[3]; print a[1] }'
```

This prints row 3, row 4, followed by row 2.

Comment: Nice, this is better than mine!

Answer (score 0):

```
ps auxfwww | sort -k2n | awk 'NR<5{a[NR]=$1" "$3" "$11} END{print a[3] ORS a[4] ORS a[2]}'
```